# Is it necessary for a method declared as async to await somewhere to be asynchronous?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

```
from aiohttp import web
import json

async def handle(request):
    response_obj = { 'status' : 'success' }
    return web.Response(text=json.dumps(response_obj))

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/', handle)

web.run_app(app)
```

I got this code snippet from this tutorial: https://tutorialedge.net/python/create-rest-api-python-aiohttp/ and wanted to know if its really asynchronous.

From what I know about asynio in Python, I think a function declared as `async` needs to `await` somewhere in it to transfer control to the event loop which will then execute something else. Since there's no `await` here in the `handle` function, I think its not really asynchronous.

Comment: Define what it means to you for something to be asynchronous.

Comment: @orlp I expect the code to not be blocked when executing this line: `return web.Response(text=json.dumps(response_obj))` Am I wrong in assuming that `non-blocking IO == asynchronous`?